# What is a PowerShell popup?

Tags: powershell, colors, console, popups, conhost

I am manually configuring the colors of my PowerShell and I am curious what a "popup" is and how I can see it? As of now it seems that only "Selected Screen Colors" changes anything. How might I cause an example of such a popup to appear so that I can see the color changes that I have made?

[image: Popup color options circled here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is from conhost.exe which is the *terminal* that *shells* like cmd and PowerShell connect to. I don't know if there are any popups in PowerShell but by default in cmd when pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> in you'll see a popup window that shows command history. You can also try <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd>

Here's an example of pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> in cmd (left) and in cmd running inside PowerShell (right)

[image: popup example]

---

## Update:

You can show the history popup in PowerShell by temporarily unloading the `PSReadLine` module with

```
Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine
```

[image: popup in powershell]